# Compile an exe file inside c++

Tags: c++

I want to create a c++ program in which

1. I can read an external file (that can be exe,dll,apk...etc...etc). That is read the file convert them into bytes and store them in an array
2. Next,I want to compile the bytes inside the array
   Now this is the tricky part i want to compile the bytes into an array just to check that if the bytes are working well
3. You may say i am converting a file into bytes and then converting those bytes back to the same file....(Yes indeed i am doing so)

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand the "compile the bytes" part. Just makes no sense. Also please next time format your question more cleanly, use paragraphs, punctuation and such things that help us that are not yourself understand what you mean (we usually do not read your mind).

Comment: Before replying, may I ask you what is the purpose of the application you are developing?

Comment: So sehe...how can i do that??? i know i can use ifstream to read a file and ofstream to write a file using a binary reader i can read the file  into buffer .......now what???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether an executable can be loaded (not quite the same as execution):

- it will succeed unless

  - there is a lack of permissions
  - the file is not accessable
  - one of the dependencies are not accessable (dependency libraries, e.g.)

Note that on UNIX, the same can be achieved using [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

.

```
// A simple program that uses LoadLibrary

#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main( void ) 
{ 
    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("input.exe"));  // or dll

    fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 

if (hinstLib != NULL)
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

    return 0;

}
```

See also

- [LoadLibrary Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [LoadLibraryEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: sehe plz help me to understand this program

Answer (score 0):

Use stream copy

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream in_memory(
            std::ios_base::out | 
            std::ios_base::in | 
            std::ios::binary);

    {   
        // reading whole file into memory
        std::ifstream ifs("input.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        in_memory << ifs.rdbuf();
    }

    {
        // optionally write it out
        std::ofstream ofs("input.exe.copy", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        ofs << in_memory.rdbuf();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't use an in-memory stage, it'll be far more efficient (and very large files will not cause problems):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream("input.exe.copy2", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary)
        << std::ifstream("input.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary).rdbuf();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you help me understand "//no in-memory stage:" ???

Comment: Now rdbuf() contains the byte of files...How can i compile the bytes in the rdbuf??

Comment: You first answer the question: "what does it mean to compile the bytes"? I think you want to do something with them, which makes the `in_memory` idea a good option (also: `rdbuf()` _reads_ the bytes, `in_memory` _contains_ the bytes)

Comment: Here what i am trying to do is rebuild the same application.....i am breaking a file into its bytes and then constructing the file again that is going reverse...however i want to do it is by using c++..I hope you understood

Comment: I did. My code does that. I suspect you are somehow expecting some code to 'interpret' the bytes (that would be: loading and executing). However, that is not a C++ job (it's the operating system's job to load and execute binaries); also, it doesn't help to create the same binary right back. If you want to get /another/ binary that does exactly the same, you can trick it with something like [`UPX executable packer`](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Allright i got it the code breaks a file into the bytes and then those bytes are written to other file....No w i f u can help me in executing those bytes not in actual environment.I am trying to work here on an virtual environment or more like an x86 emulator.where the file is checked if it would compile sucessfully...does it make any sense to you??

Comment: If the executable exists, then **obviously** it compiles successfully. That's sort of required. Writing a VM is a whole 'nother mess, and you can't just "check" and "compile" the bytes for that. You should look into how virtual machines work and how to wrap and trap an executable.

Comment: @user905481: compilation is not what you think it is. You cannot test an executable without running. However look at qemu, kvm, bochs, VirtualBox, VirtualPC, VMWare, (linux:) UserMode Linux, chroot/schroot and Xen for options on running inside a virtualized container.

Comment: Also, use (windows) [DependencyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com/) or (UNIX) ldd to test whether dependencies for loading are found.

Comment: Posted another answer for a quick-and-dirty test whether you can load a binary on windows

Comment: Thanks Sehe and peachykeen...i think i got it what i wanted

Comment: @user905481: in that case, please remember to upvote or accept the answer that helped you. Thanks